# Complement of G is connected.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

Prove that a simple graph G is 2-connected if and only if for every triple (x, y, z)
of distinct vertices, G has an x, z-path through y

Thanks!

Comment: Where, what,when? Would you mind defining what you're talking about? That's the first rule I'd write in a proof-writing seminar...

Comment: Assuming $G$ is finite, the only way it can have infinite diameter is to be disconnected. If infinite graphs are allowed, there are other ways to have infinite diameter (e.g. the graph consisting of a path extending infinitely in both directions).

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Suppose that G is disconnected, how would I prove the statement. I have a counter example for it.

Comment: Duplicate of [Given a simple graph and its complement, prove that either of them is always connected.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122184/given-a-simple-graph-and-its-complement-prove-that-either-of-them-is-always-con) In the accepted answer you have a proof that every two points in a graph $G$ can be connected by a path of length at most 2 in the complement of $G$ is $G$ is disconnected.

Comment: @freakish I don't think so. Proving connectivity does not prove the diameter length.

Comment: @user1944 Read Chris Eagle's proof. Ask questions afterwards.

Comment: That's of course under the assumption that G is disconnected. I'm not sure about the case when G is connected (and thus infinite).

Comment: @freakish You are right, it does answer my question. I was being able to find a counter example before, because that is because I did not correctly understand the definition of diameter of  a graph. It is longest shortest possible path between 2 vertices. Thank you!

Comment: The new edit of the question does not make sense to me. And now the accepted answer below doesn't make sense to nobody. The earlier question was clear to me, I don't know why clarification was needed and why everybody was talking about connectivity...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I derive my definiton of Diameter from shortest paths I don't worry about disconnected Graphs in this answer. Let $G$ be connected and infinite, that means its vertex set is infinite.

Now for every pair of vertices $v,w$ we have 3 cases:

1. $d(v,w)=1$
2. $1<d(v,w)<\infty$
3. $d(v,w)=\infty$

We now need to prove that in any case the shortest path between $v$ and $w$ in the complement of $G$ is at most $2$. Cases 2&3 are easy, because edge $vw$ is in the complement.

Now case 1: Two cases again:

Case 1a: there is a vertex $x\in G$, so that $vx,xw$ are not in $G$. Then both are in the complement, and the shortest path has length two.

Case 1b is clearly not possible: If $d(v,w)=1$ and $vx$ or $wx$ is in the Graph for every vertex $x$, then $G$ doesn't have a infinite diameter.

(EDIT: This answers the original question of OP: If the diameter of a graph $G$ is infinite then the diameter of its complement is ≤2)