# Is the complement of a directed and not strongly connected graph connected?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm aware this result holds for simple graphs:

[Given a simple graph and its complement, prove that either of them is always connected.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/122184)

Does it hold for directed and not strongly connected graphs?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Note that, if there is a counterexample, then there is a counterexample with only $3$ vertices.

Comment: Suppose the digraph $D$ is not strongly connected, and its complement $\overline D$ is not connected. Then there are two vertices $u,v$ such that there is no directed path from $u$ to $v$ in $D,$ and there is a vertex $w$ such that there is no undirected path from $u$ to $w$ in $\overline D.$ Now consider the subgraph of $D$ induced by $\{u,v,w\}.$

Comment: Thank you for your comment @bof . I am thinking since $(u,v) \in \overline{D}$ and there is no undirected path between $u$ and $w$, for $\overline{D}$ to be not connected there must be no undirected path between $v$ and $w$. However, this means that $$\{(u,w),(w,u),(v,w)(w,v)\} \subset \overline{D}$$ making $D$ connected. So, by contradiction, $\overline{D}$ must be connected. Am I right?