# The complement of a simple disconnected graph is connected.

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a simple disconnected graph. Then, there exist two vertices $x$ and $y$ that do not belong to any path in $G$. In particular, $xy$ is not an edge in $G$, which means $xy$ is an edge in $\overline{G}$. Moreover, for every $v\in V(G)\backslash\{x,y\}$, $xv$ is not an edge in $G$, or $yv$ is not an edge in $G$. This means that every vertex is adjacent to at least $x$ or $y$ in $\overline{G}$. Thus, every pair of vertices belong to a path in $\overline{G}$.

In the proof above, every pair of vertices belong to a path of at most three.
But in this proof - [Given a simple graph and its complement, prove that either of them is always connected.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122184/given-a-simple-graph-and-its-complement-prove-that-either-of-them-is-always-con?noredirect=1&lq=1) - it is shown that every pair of vertices belong to a path of length at most two. How can I modify my proof so that every pair of vertices belong to a path of length at most two?

Comment: ...you could modify it by giving the proof you linked to, instead? If that's not what you want, then I'm not sure what it is you want.